# Sl4A crashes on every script

Tags: android, crash-reports, sl4a

There was time, when SL4A worked fine on my ICS phone (rooted, ofk). Than a factory reset happend; after it everything works just fine, except problem with SL4A.

I install SL4A; it can run shell scripts.
Than I install Python for Android or Perl for Android. I can run Python or Perl scripts. Nice.
Then I reboot. After reboot any attempt to do anything with SL4A (run script or start private server(any port)) results in

```
Unfortunately, SL4A has stopped.
```

Then it crashes second time, even if I have not launched it again manually.

Forever. (Till another clean install).

It occurs with all versions of SL4A and Python apk.

[Here is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6134160/)  full log(careful: 5k+ lines of text), and [here is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6134156/) piece of log, filtered to warnings.

You  can see, that first error, that looks relevant, in all cases is

```
E/sl4a.SimpleServer:156(2564): Failed to start server.
```

I have no idea what happens.

This is not *quite* programming question, so would have asked it at android.stackexchange, but it looks that they don't even have special tag for sl4a, so I posted it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is a little too local for SO in general. It's basically a serious, but uncommon bug. You might have more joy posting the problem to the SL4A Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-scripting) and seeing what the developers can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to apps in settings and Force Stop + clear the data. This usually fixes it for me. Seems to be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did have problems with my andriod version.

Installing both SL4A and python from [here](https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android) fixed this.

More details on the original post, over here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-scripting/tOovx2HprQk